# before_destroy is not firing from update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, associations, callback

I have a student that has many courses. In the student#update action and form, I accept a list of course_ids. When that list changes, I'd like to call a certain function. The code I have *does* get called if the update_attributes creates a course_student, but *does not* get called if the update_attributes destroys a course_student. Can I get this to fire, or do I have to detect the changes myself?

```
# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :grades
  has_many :course_students, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :courses, :through => :course_students
  has_many :course_efforts, :through => :course_efforts

  # Uncommenting this line has no effect:
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_students, :allow_destroy => true

  #attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :course_students_attributes

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
...
end

# app/models/course_student.rb
class CourseStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create  :reseed_queues
  before_destroy :reseed_queues

  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student

  private

  def reseed_queues
    logger.debug "******** attempting to reseed queues"
    self.course.course_efforts.each do |ce|
      ce.reseed
    end
  end

end

# app/controllers/students_controller.rb

  def update
    params[:student][:course_ids] ||= []
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
        format.html { redirect_to(@student, :notice => 'Student was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @student.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Which version of Rails? [Possibly Related Lighthouse discussion](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4386).

Comment: Thanks, Andy. This is Rails 3, beta 4. Perhaps time to try the RC?

Comment: I tried moving the callbacks to the Student model, putting after_add and before_remove callbacks on the has_many course_students association. Same behavior! The after_add fires, but the before_remove does not.

Comment: Current workaround: I detect changes in the current list of courses. Every course that changed gets reseeded. Here's the detection line (for my future self):

@student.courses.collect{|c| c.id.to_s}.to_set ^ params[:student][:course_ids].to_set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior is documented, right on the **has_many** method. From the API documentation:

> **collection=objects**
>      Replaces the collections content by deleting and adding objects as appropriate. If the :through option is true callbacks in the join models are triggered except destroy callbacks, since deletion is direct.

I'm not sure what "since deletion is direct" means, but there we have it.

Answer (score 3):

When a record is deleted using update/update_attributes, it fires `delete` method instead of `destroy`.

`@student.update_attributes(params[:student])`

`Delete` method [skips](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks) callbacks and therefore `after_create` / `before_destroy`  would not be called.
Instead of this [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) can be used which deletes the record and also support callbacks.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses, allow_destroy: true`

`@student.update_attributes(courses_attributes: [ {id: student_course_association_id, _destroy: 1 } ])`

Answer (score 1):

Accepts nested attributes requires a flag to trigger nested destroy.  Atleast it did back when.

Comment: Excellent catch, McClain. And I was hopeful, but changing to this:
>>> class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_students, :allow_destroy => true
<<<
did not help. With or without allow_destroy, the record gets deleted from the database, and the callback does not happen.

Comment: Just for fun, since there aren't really any course_student attributes to accept (just the collection_ids=), I removed accepts_nested_attributes_for entirely. Same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `dependent: :destroy`, it will honour that. Note that if you are using `has_many` `through:`, one needs to add that option to both.

```
  has_many :direct_associations, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  has_many :indirect_associations, through: :direct_associations, dependent: :destroy
```

(I have used that in Rails 3, I bet it will work on Rails 4 too)

Comment: Thank you, Carlos.

I just checked the Rails API for 4.2.1 (at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) and it still says before_destroy callbacks will not be triggered when using collection=.

Answer (score 0):

Should your `CourseStudent` specify `belongs_to :student, :dependent => :destroy`, it seems like a CourseStudent record would not be valid without a Student.

Trying to follow the LH discussion I linked to above, and [this one](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2765) I'd also try moving the `before_destroy` callback in CourseStudent below the `belongs_to`. The linked example demonstrates how the order of callbacks matters with an `after_create`, perhaps the same applies to `before_destroy`. And of course, since you're using Edge Rails, I'd also try the RC, maybe there was a bug they fixed.

Failing those things, I'd try to make a really simple Rails app with two models that demonstrates the problem and post it to Rails' Lighthouse.

Comment: In student.rb, I added :dependent => :destroy to the has_many :course_students, so if a student gets destroyed, so will the course_student, not the other way around (although it doesn't make sense for either to exist without the other).

I also moved before_destroy to after :belongs_to, and the code behaves the same. I have not yet tried the RC, and I'm not quite using edge Rails. I'm using RC4 because Heroku supports it for the moment and I'd have to migrate a couple developers.

I'm hopeful of getting a simple work-around before I have to detect which items get deleted myself.

Comment: I haven't used nested attributes much. Does the `Dirty` [module stuff](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html) work with nested attributes. I was thinking it might make your own detection of deleted associated records easier. Maybe something like Parent.child.changed? in a method that is called as a `before_save` that does the delete if necessary. Just reaching at this point though, not using Rails 3 yet, and haven't used nested attributes in over a year. :(

Comment: Andy, I removed the accept_nested_attributes_for, since there were no real attributes in there; just the list of ids. The code behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to leave a comment, so I'll just add an answer entry.

Just encountered the same bug. After hours of trying to figure this issue out and an hour of google-ing, I stumbled to this question by chance. Along with the linked LH ticket, and quote from the API, it now makes sense. Thank you!

While googling, found an old ticket. Direct link does not work, but google cache has a copy.
Just check Google for cached version of dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/7743

Seems like a patch never made it to Rails.